# MVCSitemapProvider Issue with custom Route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider, asp.net-mvc-sitemap

I having difficulty to use the MVCSitemapProvider to generate a sitemap my case is this:

I have this :

```
 routes.MapRoute("Blog", "Blog/{id}/{seoName}", new { controller = "Blog", action = "ViewBlog", seoName = "" }, new { id = @"^\d+$" });
```

and I am using this as a atribute to my controller

```
            [MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Blog", Key = "ViewBlog", ParentKey = "Blog",Route="Blog")]
```

the issue is the sitemap.xml contains this :

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>http://localhost:7872/</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://localhost:7872/#</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://localhost:7872/Blog</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://localhost:7872/Home/About</loc>
</url>
</urlset>
```

My route is mapping to this URL :  `<loc>http://localhost:7872/#</loc>` when I use the route=Blog

It was supposed to be something like this : `localhost:7872/blog/idhere/friendurlName`

the URL works fine, but I am trying to improve SEO and Sitemap is pretty much necessary 
I am not sure how to set this up. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [a dynamic node provider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider) to make each blog post into a separate node. You also need to register the "id" and "seoName" route parameters with MvcSiteMapProvider or it will not be able to match the route or build the correct URL.

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(DynamicNodeProvider = "MyNamespace.BlogDynamicNodeProvider, MyAssembly", Route = "Blog")]
public ActionResult ViewBlog(int id, string seoName)
{
    // Retrieve your blog post here...

    return View();
}
```

And in a code file in your project...

```
public class BlogDynamicNodeProvider : DynamicNodeProviderBase
{
    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode node)
    {
        // BlogEntities would be your entity framework context class
        // or repository.
        using (var entities = new BlogEntities())
        {
            // Create a node for each blog post
            foreach (var blogPost in entities.BlogPosts)
            {
                DynamicNode dynamicNode = new DynamicNode();
                dynamicNode.Title = blogPost.Title;
                dynamicNode.ParentKey = "Blog";
                dynamicNode.Key = "BlogPost_" + blogPost.Id;
                dynamicNode.RouteValues.Add("id", blogPost.Id);
                dynamicNode.RouteValues.Add("seoName", blogPost.SeoName);

                yield return dynamicNode;
            }
        }
    }
}
```